# How to call Vapor from different domain?

Tags: cors, vapor

I have only a simple route. BE and FE is in different domains, how to call BE from FE to get response? FE is React.

I tried to add setting specified here: https://github.com/vapor/documentation/blob/master/3.0/docs/vapor/middleware.md without any luck.

FE refuse call without HTTP status error code. Cleared cache in browser.

[image]

I tried to add those line to the route, without luck:

```
public func routes(_ router: Router) throws {

    router.grouped(CORSMiddleware()).post([Page].self, at: "/releases") { (req, pages) -> Future<[Page]> in
       req.response().http.headers.add(name: "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", value:"Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
        req.response().http.headers.add(name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value:"*")
```

When BE is called from `Postman`, it works, not from FE. Breakpoint is not even hit from FE.

I see some errors in browser, and no response at all from BE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why have you posted a picture of code? What does *"without any luck"* mean, exactly (give a [mcve])?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs *(now gone)*:

> Given that thrown errors are immediately returned to the client, the `CORSMiddleware` must be listed before the `ErrorMiddleware`; otherwise the HTTP error response will be returned without CORS headers, and cannot be read by the browser.

Hence, you have to register your `CORSMiddleware` *before* the `ErrorMiddleware`, like this:

```
var middlewares = MiddlewareConfig()
let corsConfiguration = CORSMiddleware.Configuration(
    allowedOrigin: .all,
    allowedMethods: [.GET, .POST, .PUT, .OPTIONS, .DELETE, .PATCH],
    allowedHeaders: [.accept, .authorization, .contentType, .origin, .xRequestedWith, .userAgent, .accessControlAllowOrigin]
)
let corsMiddleware = CORSMiddleware(configuration: corsConfiguration)
middlewares.use(corsMiddleware)
middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self)
middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self)
services.register(middlewares)
```

Also worth noting is that you should only configure your access control checks in *either* your vapor application, *or* on your server directly, such as in the NGINX configuration. If you set both, the access controls will fail.